# how to create input field with increment of number in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically add an `input` field with a value that increments when you add rows. This is so that I can all save them to a database. The `input` field with the number increment will be the reference number of particulars for my invoice. 
Your help will be greatly appreciated!

```js
function autoCalcSetup() {
  $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc('destroy');

  $('form[name=cart] tr[name=line_items]').jAutoCalc({
    keyEventsFire: true,
    decimalPlaces: 2,
    emptyAsZero: true
  });

  $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc({
    decimalPlaces: 2
  });
}

autoCalcSetup();

$('button[name=remove]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this).parents('form')
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  autoCalcSetup();
});

$('button[name=add]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $table = $(this).parents('table');
  var $top = $table.find('tr[name=line_items]').first();
  var $bottom = $table.find('tr[name=endin_colz]').first();

  var $new = $top.clone(true);  
  $new.jAutoCalc('destroy');
  $new.insertBefore($bottom);
  $new.find('input[name=number]').val('2');
  autoCalcSetup();
});
```

Comment: Also, be sure to explain exactly how your code isn't working as expected. I see that you may have intended to post code, but you haven't mentioned what the actual problem is.

Comment: This seems entirely pointless. If the input holds an incremental number, forget adding anything to the DOM and just use the index of the entity you send in the array to your server.

Comment: Also please create a [mcve]  when possible. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant HTML, CSS and frameworks

Comment: Yes I figured I wanted the id of each row so that I can sort by the id number and it worked sorry I will be more prices with lots of example next time. by the way thank you so much!!